# admin bar disappears completely in 2010 theme

Tags: plugins, admin-bar

I've installed a plugin to upload local avatars through a front end form to edit user profiles provided by another plugin (user frontend). While the upload and modification of the db seems to work just fine, clicking the update button of the form does apparently lead to the WP 3.1 admin bar no longer being rendered for some unexplicable reason. There's simply no $wp_admin_bar object being created. I have no idea what could possibly cause this, but I have also no idea how to activate the admin bar if the default init function fails.

Does anyone have an idea for me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

And I found the solution via another unrelated admin bar question.

If anyone ever comes across this problem with the user_frontend plugin or any other plugin posting data from a custom form - apparently WP unchecks the two admin bar related check boxes if a set of data is sent to update the user profile that does not include the check box values. Accordingly, WP dutifully didn't render the admin bar while I was logged in.

I've contacted the plugin author to look into this.